# How to redefine stderr out and stdout out to separately logs?

Tags: python

How to redefine stderr out and stdout out to separately logs files using logging module ? For example stderr.log and stdout.log files ?

Comment: do you want to redirect `sys.stdout`, `sys.stderr` to files or do you want message produced with an aid of `logging` module to go to files?

Answer (score 8):

You can simply replace `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` with custom file-like objects:

```
import sys

sys.stdout = open('stdout.log', 'a')
sys.stderr = open('stderr.log', 'a')
```

To undo:

```
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
```

For more information, read the [`sys` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.stdin).

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys


class OutDevice():
    def write(self, s):
        # do whatever
        pass

class ErrDevice():
    def write(self, s):
        # do whatever
        pass

sys.stdout = OutDevice()  
sys.stdout = ErrDevice()  

# to restore
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__ 
sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
```